# Can't cast postgresql interval into C# TimeSpan

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, timespan

I can't cast postgresql interval into `TimeSpan`:

```
item.TSHours = dr["Hours"] == DBNull.Value ? TimeSpan.Zero : (TimeSpan)dr["Hours"];
```

is throwing:

> "Specified cast is not valid"

but `dr["Hours"]` returns the value `"06:00:00"` :/

What am I doing wrong? I was trying few versions of npgsql, but nothing changed.

> dr["Hours"] is NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlInterval

EDIT:

The only way I could make it work is to use:

```
new TimeSpan(((NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlInterval)dr["Hours"]).TotalTicks)
```

Answer (score 3):

At least you can't cast string into TimeSpan directly. 
This will work:

```
item.TSHours = dr["Hours"] == DBNull.Value ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.Parse(dr["Hours"].ToString());
```

from [npgsql APi](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/api/NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlInterval.html) docs:

> To avoid forcing unnecessary provider-specific concerns on users who need not be concerned with them a call to GetValue on a field containing an NpgsqlInterval value will return a TimeSpan rather than an NpgsqlInterval.

Comment: i was trying like this also, but than i got "The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits" when for example dr["Hours"] is "73:30:00"